# Convert WebStorage (JS/JQuery) content into Blade-ready variable

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel

so I'm currently saving local data via WebStorage. Was wondering if there's a way to convert it to a Laravel Blade-ready variable upon page load. Here's what I've done so far.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("data")); 
    
    // initialize php code
    <?php $var = ?> data <?php ; ?>
});
```

However this doesnt work since it breaks PHP ruling

Comment: Variables in javascript are only available for the browser (client) not for the server. PHP variables are only available for the server nor for the browser. So what you try to do is not possible.

Comment: sucks, that's my only option to run. I've tried cookies but it has a limit of 5MB

Comment: Why do you want to save 5mb of data on the client if the data can be requested from server whenever you want?

Comment: i'm copying the idea of pcpartpicker's saving logic. even if im not registered member, i can still save the build i want in my local